# tf view_frames missing

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just did an install of the full desktop version of ROS Groovy as per the instructions on the install page. I just built a transform tree, and would like use the view_frames function in the tf package, but it's not there. Could I have missed installing it somehow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53739/tf-view_frames-missing/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out view_frames is still included in Groovy, but is in `/opt/ros/groovy/bin` so you can run it directly from the command line (assuming $PATH is set correctly). It seems this has happened with other packages. More info here: http://answers.ros.org/question/54132/pcl_ros-bag_to_pcd-not-found/

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3